# Best practice for rosdep, ubuntu packages, and others

Tags: ros, rosdep, ubuntu, best-practices, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

As already discussed in [question #2701](http://answers.ros.org/question/2701/multiple-ros-release-support-in-rosdepyaml), I am working on the release of the  [modular_cloud_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/modular_cloud_matcher) package.

This package depends on [libnabo](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libnabo) and [libpointmatcher](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher), for which I provide Ubuntu packages for the last 4 releases (from Lucid to Oneiric) on my PPA. As there is currently no way to tell rosdep to fetch packages from a PPA, in a previous discussion with Tully Foote we agreed that the user will have to install these packages by hand.

The question then is whether I should add these as package dependency in the rosdep.yaml, and if so, what to do with non-ubuntu systems. Should I provide a script that fetches the packages and "cmakes/makes/makes install" them? If so, is there a way to provide an "other" or "default" target in rosdep.yaml? Or should I leave these dependencies out and let the user install libnabo and libpointmatcher by hand?

I will be happy to hear your opinion on the best practice in this context. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11879/best-practice-for-rosdep,-ubuntu-packages,-and-others/) by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've been moving away from wrapping system-installable libraries in ROS packages.  It leads to less portable code, as you end up using ROS-specific linking methods to use these libraries.

Instead, as much as possible, we are now trying to:

- provide debs for these libraries on Ubuntu (we will hopefully make this toolchain available for packages.ros.org, but it still needs a lot of work)
- provide an exemplar 'source rosdep' ([REP 112](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0112.html)) that is somewhat equivalent to the download_and_unpack-style builds, except they attempt to do system installs.

A valid criticism of source rosdeps is that they don't come with an uninstall mechanism.  That said, the main role of the source rosdeps, IMHO, is to provide a starting point to people on other platforms.  They are generally equivalent to what that user would have done if they had to manually download the source and install on their own.

We try to shy away from PPAs for libraries, as Ubuntu does, as they lack safety guards to prevent downstream issues.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I would recommend to create a ROS package for both libnabo and libpointmatcher until they become "first class" dependencies packaged on most of the major Linux distributions.

I recognize that it is preferable to have system dependencies over ROS dependencies, but do not forget that there is other Linux distributions that Ubuntu. What about the Fedora users for instance? They would still have to build and install your dependencies by hand.

The only other solution would be to use the ability in rosdep.yaml to put arbitraty shell code to download and build the package on non Ubuntu platforms. This is wrong for many reasons :)

Therefore, the only other solution is to package the dependencies as ROS packages. It is easy to do (look at [this for instance](http://https://github.com/laas/vision_visp/tree/master/visp)) and it will ensure that *all* ROS users will be able to use your package.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2